# laravel relationships beetween table foreign key

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

I have a problem. I want to create a dropdown box with the name's from a table in my database andstore just an id from that name in other table (that id is a foreign key). I will show you my code

```
//acao model
public function estado() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Estado');
}

//estado model
public function acao()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Acao');
}
```

AcaoController@Create:

```
public function create()
{
  $estado = Estado::pluck('nome', 'id');
  return view('Backoffice.acoes.criar_acao', compact('estado'));
}
```

AcaoController@Store:

```
$data = Acao::create([
      'estado_id' => $data[estado_id],
    ]);
return redirect()->back();
```

This way the store doesn´t work and i think that this code doesn´t work with the relationship beetween acao and estado.

Can anyone help me please Thanks

Comment: what is the error u seen

Comment: and your `criar_acao` view?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with `Mass Assignment` so do this in `acao` thats has `estado_id` just add it to your fillable array. add this line tour your model

```
protected $fillable = ['name','estado_id'];
```